# Align flex-column items to left and right within one parent Div

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox, toast

In an Angular app, I am trying to stack Bootstrap `toast` elements in a customized vertical manner, which is putting certain `toast` to page left side(`align-items-start` style), certain `toast` to page right side(`align-items-end` style), but unfortunately they are all under one parent `Div`.

Code here:

1. parent component template

```html
 <div class="toast-container d-flex flex-column align-items-start">

     <app-share-comment [comment]='comment' *ngFor="let comment of comments" >
   </app-share-comment>

 </div>
```

2. Child `app-share-comment` template and css and typeScript

```html
  <div class="toast" [ngStyle]="style" data-autohide="false">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <strong class="mr-auto text-primary">{{comment.username}}</strong>
      <time class="timeago" [dateTime]="commentTime"></time>    
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      {{comment.comment}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.toast{
    min-width: 12vw;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0.6rem;
    position: relative
}
```

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    (<any>$('.toast')).toast('show');

    this.style = this.getStyle()
  }

  getStyle(): Object {
    if (this.comment.username == 'wayne'){
      return {
        left : 12 +'rem'
      };
    }
```

With current code, I am getting below effect:
[image]

Expected effect : **If items are choosen to align right, they should align with right border, instead of left border. But other items remain left border aligned.**
[image]

Is it possible to realize in Css way?
I tried many flex properties but no luck, could anyone help?

I also created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbp7ua

Comment: if you give me an example on stackblitz i can help you

Comment: Try adding `align-self: flex-end` to your `getStyle(): Object {
    if (this.comment.username == 'wayne'){
      return {
        left : 12 +'rem'
      };
    }`

Comment: provide a stackblitz and i can resolve the css there.

Comment: Let me make a stackblitz. BTW, @disinfor , i have tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbp7ua?file=src/index.html , please help, thanks~

Comment: THEY ALREADY SHOW ON LEFT AND RIGHT

Comment: what exactly is required?

Comment: If items align to right, i want them to align with right border, instead of left border.

Comment: can you provide screenshot of expected outcome?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is already there in main post.

Comment: please check the solution, and if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your provided stackblitz i made following changes:-

**Working Stackblitz :-**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkgnym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

**app.component.css :-**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.toast-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.justify-content-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.my-toast {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="toast-container">
  <div class="my-toast" [ngClass]="{'justify-content-end': comment?.username === 'right'}" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
    <hello [comment]='comment'>
    </hello>
  </div>
</div>
```

**hello.component.ts(template)**

```
<div class="toast">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="mr-auto text-primary">{{ comment.username }}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        {{ comment.comment }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

**hello.component.ts (style)**

```
.toast {
        border: solid;
        min-width: 12vw;
        margin: 0.6rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: max-content;
      }
      :host {
        display: flex;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you!  Aakash, you just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```js
getStyle(): Object {
    if (this.comment.username == "right") {
      return {
        margin: '10px 0 0px auto'
      };
    }
  }
```